# post checkbox value

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to post values of check boxes on booking.php page.

There are many checkboxes on the page but I don't know how to post on `booking.php` page.

```
<form name="booking.php" method="post">
    <label for="tour" class="tour-label">Add to Tour List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="booking-check" value="Desert Safari" />
</form>
<div class="details"><a href="booking.php">Book Selected Tours</a></div>
```

Answer (score 58):

There are many links that lets you know how to handle post values from checkboxes in php.
Look at this link: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Single check box

HTML code:

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
    Do you need wheelchair access?
    <input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="Yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['formWheelchair']) && $_POST['formWheelchair'] == 'Yes') 
{
    echo "Need wheelchair access.";
}
else
{
    echo "Do not Need wheelchair access.";
}    

?>
```

Check box group

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
    Which buildings do you want access to?<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="A" />Acorn Building<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="B" />Brown Hall<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="C" />Carnegie Complex<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="D" />Drake Commons<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="E" />Elliot House

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
 /form>

<?php
  $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);

    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Then, if I understand the result of a multiple selection is an array with all values in it ? Must we use `[ ]` for that purpose ?

Comment: @Sébastien Garcia-Roméo: yes! on the checkbox group code, at the very end, you can see that there is a for loop being use to loop through selected values.

Comment: In this case I tried the same code and returns "You selected 2 door(s): on on ... I don't understand why returns "on" when I'm sending the checkboxes values.

Answer (score 11):

in normal time, checkboxes return an on/off value.

you can verify it with this code:

```
<form action method="POST">
      <input type="checkbox" name="hello"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['hello'])) echo('<p>'.$_POST['hello'].'</p>');
?>
```

this will return

```
<p>off</p>
```

or

```
<p>on</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

inside your `form`.

and add `action` into your `form` tag for example:

```
<form action="booking.php" method="post">
```

It's post your form into action which you choose.

From php you can get this value by

```
$_POST['booking-check'];
```

Comment: I think it's also important to note that checkbox input's are only available via $_POST if they are checked - otherwise they are not set.

Answer (score 1):

In your form tag, rather than

```
name="booking.php"
```

use

```
action="booking.php"
```

And then, in booking.php use

```
$checkValue = $_POST['booking-check'];
```

Also, you'll need a submit button in there

```
<input type='submit'>
```

Comment: i did but didn't found print values on booking.php page

Comment: The code above won't print your results, just get it from the server. If you need to print it out, add `print $checkValue;`

Comment: Thanks! I am just learning php online. that is why having problems.

Comment: sir i am having problem. when checking multiple boxes it doesn't print multiple values if i put submit button without checkbox form.  if you visit this link you ll understand better: http://intriguedesigners.com/test/dubai-tours.php

Comment: You'll need to repeat `$checkValue = $_POST['booking-check'];` for each check box, using different input names and PHP variables for each.