# Insert array value into database

Tags: php, postgresql, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes whose value I want to insert into a database. The checkbox declaration is like this:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"       
onClick="toggle(this, '.$x.')" /> All</td>';
```

And here I try to insert it (together with other variables, that doesnt really matter). So, the other variables are inserted, while this one isnt.

```
<?php
    ob_start(); //eliminates buffer collisions
    require_once('connect_db.php'); 
    $id = time(); //creates a unique id using the unix time
    $check =  $_POST['check_list[0]']; 
    $result = pg_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO lecturer VALUES ($id, '$_POST[name]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[department]', $check)");  


?>
```

What is wrong with my syntax? Cause all the values are inserted, besides that of the checkbox.

Comment: Can you show days check boxes?

Comment: Isn't it just an edit of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233807/how-can-store-the-values-of-dynamically-generated-checkboxes-in-a-table ?

Comment: @JakubKania Yes it is. Because the question was to broad and i decided to delete it and ask for this part only

Comment: @amygrimaldi but you didn't delete it.

Comment: @HuzoorBux : There are no days check boxes. It's only a for loop with $x as the iterative variable and the above line inside it.

Comment: @JakubKania : Internet connection issues. My bad. Anyway, managed to delete it just now

Comment: Should UPDATE have a WHERE clause?

Comment: @BigScar: Good point. But the problem is not at the update (actually I edited the post so you can see that I am not using update anymore). The problem is that I cant access the value of the checkbox as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should access the value in such way:

`$_POST['check_list'][0]`

Also, do not forget that non-selected checkboxes do not produces $_POST values, so
if you did not select any checkbox, then `$_POST['check_list']` will be empty.

Please, take a look here [post checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781270/post-checkbox-value)

Comment: I managed to solve mostly the issue, but I was only getting the 'true' values and couldnt understand why ... Your answer clarified it for me. Thanks!