# add values into selection table from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched everywhere and still cannot find the answer. Can anybody help?

I have a PHP form that consists of a textbox (with data that will go into column `name_id`) and a checkbox, that has the option to go to 5 different MySQL tables:

```
'table A'
'table B'
'table C'
'table D'
'table E'
```

People can choose which table they want, and the `name_id` will go to the tables selected.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are there 5 tables instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my Answere in different from @RandD-SexyBoy- . my sql query is different from  @RandD-SexyBoy- he has used `$sql = "INSERT INTO $tables[$i](nameID_column);` with out `VALUES (:nameID_column)`
were is have used `$sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$v." (name_id) VALUES (?)"`

Here are 3 cases the user responds

case first : user may select a single table

case second : user may select multiple tables. here we must use `foreach()` loop and dynamic sql queries.

case third : user may not select any table in this case we must give user a message `table not selected`

html form :

`

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name_id" required>

            <p>select your table to add data</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="tblA">Table A<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="tblB">Table B<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="tblC">Table C<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="tblD">Table D<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="tblE">Table E<br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

php file :

```
 <?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','admin','demo');

    if(!$con){
        die("Connection ".$con->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name_id = $_POST['name_id'];

        $tables = $_POST['tables']; 

        if(!empty($tables)){
            foreach($tables as $key=>$v){
                $sql = $con->stmt_init();
                if($sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$v." (name_id) VALUES (?)")){
                    $sql->bind_param($name_id);
                    $sql->execute();

                    echo "DATA INSERTED";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Error".$con->error;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "You have not selected tables";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I got this message   Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in ................. on line 350
DATA INSERTED

Comment: ok than change this `$sql->bind_param($name_id);` to this `$sql->bind_param('i',$name_id);`. if error you still receive the post the code here in comment box. And if you want to know more about bind param than click on [this  link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0):

So one naive approach could be, when the user submits the form, on your php side, you check which checkboxes are ticked and your condition could be something like this

```
if(checkbox_for_table_A) {// insert query}

if(checkbox_for_table_B) {// insert query}

if(checkbox_for_table_C) {// insert query}

if(checkbox_for_table_D) {// insert query}

if(checkbox_for_table_E) {// insert query}
```

This way if one checkbox is selected it will save into that table, if more than one tables are selected, it will go in that table.

Hope this helps! Ask any doubt you get in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from sources : [post checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781270/post-checkbox-value) and tutorial http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/, you can use this approach :

HTML Form :

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name_id" /><br />

    Select your database: <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formTables[]" value="A" />Table A<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formTables[]" value="B" />Table B<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formTables[]" value="C" />Table C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formTables[]" value="D" />Table D<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formTables[]" value="E" />Table E<br />

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Now the  PHP script :

```
<?php
  $pdo_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'demouser', 'demopass');
  $tables = $_POST['formTables'];
  if(empty($tables)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any tables.");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($tables);

    echo("You selected $N table(s): ");

    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO $tables[$i](nameID_column);
      $stmt = $pdo_connection->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nameID_column', $_POST['name_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute(); 
      echo("Your ID Name was inserted into table $tables[$i] ! <br /> ");
    }
  }
?>
```