# Checkbox not sending value when check on form submitting

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm having issues with my code not submitting a checkbox value when checked on form.

```
<form action="codetest.php" method="get">              
  <div class=" form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="new-shooter" value="New"/>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="new">
      New
    </label>
  </div>
  <button name="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Register</strong></button>
  <button name="register" type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Clear</strong></button>
  <button name="back" type="submit" formaction="registration.php" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Back</strong></button>
 </form>
```

When I click the checkbox then Register I get this in the address bar:

> codetest.php?register=Register

Can't find any thing wrong with my code.
I'm also using bootstrap 4 for my css.

Comment: All form inputs should have a name attribute. Your checkbox doesn't.

Comment: Does this help any? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781270/post-checkbox-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your checkbox a `name`, say, `name = "checkbox"`.

```
<form action="codetest.php" method="get">              
  <div class=" form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="new-shooter" value="New"/>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="new">
      New
    </label>
  </div>
  <button name="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Register</strong></button>
  <button name="register" type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Clear</strong></button>
  <button name="back" type="submit" formaction="registration.php" class="btn btn-primary"><strong>Back</strong></button>
 </form>
```