# PHPMailer with HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, contact-form

Sorry for my bad English :(
I got a big problem here, I have html homepage with contact form in there. I would like to have this form send with PHPMailer, when I send a message I get this but without text :/ I see only the sample text like "Here is the subject". Can someone help me please?

here is the phpmailer.php code:

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.test.de';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'MY EMAIL';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'MY PASSWORT!';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('MY EMAIL');
    $mail->addAddress('MY EMAIL');     // Add a recipient



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

MY EMAIL ist just for secure here

And here ist the code from the html contact form:

```html
<!-- Contact Form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <form action="phpmailer_new.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Contact Form -->
```

Cheers Yves

Comment: instead of `phpmailer` why don't you try `mail` function by `php`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I think that I don't have the knowledge to make that. xD

Comment: No, don't use `mail()`; it's considerably more difficult to produce and send valid email messages using it, and [it's prone to vulnerabilities](https://exploitbox.io/paper/Pwning-PHP-Mail-Function-For-Fun-And-RCE.html). PHPMailer acts as a front-end for `mail()` by default and deals with man of the problems it causes, but sending via SMTP is both faster and safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your variables $_POST in your PHPmailer script :

```
  <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'src/Exception.php';
    require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.test.de';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'MY EMAIL';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'MY PASSWORT!';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('MY EMAIL');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['mail']);     // Add a recipient



        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mail->Body    = $_POST['text'];

        $mail->send();
        //echo 'Message has been sent';
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/contact.php');
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe u can help me by my last problem ... now the message sends and when I hit the send button it takes me to a new site where stands "Message has been sent" is it possible to make this so that you stay on the side and come not to a new one?

Comment: i changed the code, at the end i added an redirection to http://www.example.com/contact.php, so change this url with the page that you want see after sending message

Comment: i m glad that it helped you, have a nice day

Comment: okay ... no rly the last question xD sorry for being a noob in this :-D but u helped me so quick :) I would like to add in the form 2 checkboxes is there a special code for checkbox to put it in the html and php document or is ist so easy that I put the code for checkbox from my template in the html of my website and write the checkbox code in the php?

Comment: check this link to add checkboxes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781270/post-checkbox-value